# Filtering datatable between date ranges

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

i need your help. i create a table from datatables. i want to filter the data in table using date ranges but my code didn't work. i know there is many issue & question like this in here. i checked it before but still can't solved my problem

```js
// The plugin function for adding a new filtering routine
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex){
 var dateStart = parseDateValue($("#min").val());
 var dateEnd = parseDateValue($("#max").val());
 // aData represents the table structure as an array of columns, so the script access the date value 
 // in the first column of the table via aData[0]
 var evalDate= parseDateValue(aData[0]);

 if (evalDate >= dateStart && evalDate <= dateEnd) {
  return true;
 }
 else {
  return false;
 }
 
});

// Function for converting a dd M yyyy date value into a numeric string for comparison (example 12 Oct 2010 becomes 20101012
function parseDateValue(rawDate) {
 var month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
 var dateArray = rawDate.split(" ");
 var numMonth = Number(month.indexOf(dateArray[1]))+1;
 if(numMonth.toString().length<2){
  numMonth = "0"+numMonth;
 } else {
  numMonth = numMonth.toString();
 }
 var parsedDate = dateArray[2] + numMonth + dateArray[0];
 return parsedDate;
}

$(document).ready(function(){   
 var oTable = $('#table-mutasi').dataTable({
  "iDisplayLength": 25,
  "filter":   false,
  "lengthChange": false,
  "ordering": false,
  "info":     false
 });
 
 $('#min,#max').datepicker({
  format: "dd M yyyy",
  weekStart: 1,
  daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0",
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true
 });
 
 // Add event listeners to the two range filtering inputs
 $('#min,#max').change(function(){ oTable.fnDraw(); });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div class="form-group">
 <div class="input-group input-daterange">
  <input type="text" id="min" class="form-control" value="04 Nov 2016">
  <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
  <input type="text" id="max" class="form-control" value="04 Nov 2016">
 </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" id="table-mutasi">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Date</th>
   <th>Product</th>
   <th>Point</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>30 Oct 2016 16:20</td>
   <td>PX5</td>
   <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>02 Nov 2016 16:20</td>
   <td>PLN100</td>
   <td>250</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>04 Nov 2016 16:20</td>
   <td>IJ10</td>
   <td>50</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

could you analyze that code, what exactly wrong

Comment: Do you know there is a plugin for that? https://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/row-based/range_dates

Comment: i know. but i use this tutorial [link](http://www.thoughtdelimited.org/thoughts/demos/dataTablesDateRange/). and i found many plugin. but the most important is `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push`. all plugin is use this

Comment: You disabled filtering...... `"filter":   false,` Remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You disabled table filtering in dataTable() initialization..
Correct to

```
var oTable = $('#table-mutasi').dataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info":     false
});
```

Check this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhoub9gp/1/)

Comment: Beat me to it, though I'd also replace the 'orrible date parsing with momentjs (nothing wrong with a little bit of cheating (standing on the shoulders of giants)). The default dates will also mean that nothing will be displayed initially so I'd probably spin through the values and set the min the the earliest and the max to the latest... my effort: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/8mgu8zux/

Comment: @annoyingmouse it make my code more short. thank you